# How do I open Firefox and set a new profile as default? (selenium and Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-profile

Okay so I wasted a whole day self research and failed. So help?
I made a profile and all I'm trying to do is open Firefox under that profile as and have it set as a default.

Here is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

ff_options = Options()
#profile
binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:\\Users\\bravoj\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\7k4o5psw.CCC Deafualt')
ff_driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path='C:\\Users\\bravoj\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe')
#fire fox driver

ff_driver.get('about:profiles')
```

Comment: Could you mention which version of Firefox browser  and webdriver driver you are using?

Comment: @KiranAntony its  70.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Selenium indeed uses a copy of the profile, though that ought not to cause any problems. I think your issue has more to do with session cookies vs. persistent cookies.

On support.mozilla.org is a list indicating what information is actually stored in your profile. Note that cookies are among these, however session-cookies are not stored in cookies.sqlite which is the reason Selenium cannot rebuild your session since it does not appear in the profile.

Many sites, however, offer a remember-me or a stay-logged-in option on their login page which, if used, will store a persistent cookie by which the session can be restored. I used the following script to test this out with gmail,

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "https://mail.google.com"
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/71v1uczn.default')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: I ended up copying your code and only changing the directory of the profile to mine. I got the error that I need the gecko driver, i'm assuming it wont work without it? I was hoping to actually open up the actual browser instead of the testing environment.

Comment: Giving "default" in the profiling should open the real browser

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm still new and have only been doping this for 5 days. but could I get an example? because I changed the the profile to the default profile and still didn't work.

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
url = "<targeted website>"
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:\\Users\\<admin>\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\t18zcb43.default')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.get(url)